# Is there anyway to handy convert a dictionary to String?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tostring

I found the default implemtation of ToString in the dictionary is not what I want. I would like to have `{key=value, ***}`.

Any handy way to get it?

Comment: Is this for visualization in the debugger only?  Or is this string intended to be user-facing?

Comment: I think this is very well done by JSON serializer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639094/most-efficient-dictionaryk-v-tostring-with-formatting

Comment: For future reference, the default `ToString` implementation looks something like this: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]`.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Try this extension method:

```
public static string ToDebugString<TKey, TValue> (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(",", dictionary.Select(kv => kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value).ToArray()) + "}";
}
```

Comment: I don't see a need for the `ToArray()`, neither for the `ToString()`'s.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: `ToArray()` is really needed, if you're using version lower than NET 4.0

Comment: exactly like map.toString() in java ;)

Answer (score 226):

If you just want to serialize for debugging purposes, the shorter way is to use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join):

```cs
var asString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dictionary);
```

This works because `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

## Example

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"key1", "value1"},
    {"key2", "value2"},
    {"key3", "value3"},
}));
/*
[key1, value1]
[key2, value2]
[key3, value3]
*/
```

Comment: Note that this requires .NET 4

Comment: Doesn't work with `ListDictionary`. Otherwise great, upvoting

Comment: It works wonderful for simple types. But if your values are classes you have to find another solution. Answer by @Matías Fidemraizer can help in this situation  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899279/2028619

Answer (score 13):

How about an extension-method such as:

```
public static string MyToString<TKey,TValue>
      (this IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

    var items = from kvp in dictionary
                select kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value;

    return "{" + string.Join(",", items) + "}";
}
```

Example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {4, "a"},
    {5, "b"}
};

Console.WriteLine(dict.MyToString());
```

Output:

```
{4=a,5=b}
```

Comment: Breath and specify it's an extension method :D

Answer (score 9):

Maybe:

```
string.Join
(
    ",",
    someDictionary.Select(pair => string.Format("{0}={1}", pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value.ToString())).ToArray()
);
```

First you iterate each key-value pair and format it as you'd like to see as string, and later convert to array and join into a single string.

Answer (score 8):

No handy way. You'll have to roll your own.

```
public static string ToPrettyString<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("{");
    foreach (var pair in dict)
    {
        str.Append(String.Format(" {0}={1} ", pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }
    str.Append("}");
    return str.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is helpful as it works on pre-.NET3.5 code (without linq support)

Answer (score 4):

I got this simple answer.. Use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) Class for this.

And you can simply call Serialize method with Dictionary object as argument.

Example:

```
var dct = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dct.Add("sam","shekhar");
dct.Add("sam1","shekhar");
dct.Add("sam3","shekhar");
dct.Add("sam4","shekhar");
Console.WriteLine(js.Serialize(dct));
```

Output:

```
{"sam":"shekhar","sam1":"shekhar","sam3":"shekhar","sam4":"shekhar"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Linq, you could try something like this:

```
String.Format("{{{0}}}", String.Join(",", test.OrderBy(_kv => _kv.Key).Zip(test, (kv, sec) => String.Join("=", kv.Key, kv.Value))));
```

where "test" is your dictionary.  Note that the first parameter to Zip() is just a placeholder since a null cannot be passed).

If the format is not important, try

```
String.Join(",", test.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key));
```

Which will give you something like

```
[key,value], [key,value],...
```

Comment: I like the Linq expression @Tim provided more.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    {"A", 100.0 },
    {"B", 200.0 },
    {"C", 50.0 }
};

string text = dic.Select(kvp => kvp.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Value of text: `[A, 100], [B, 200], [C, 50]`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Keys of the Dictionary and print them together with the value...

```
public string DictToString(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    string toString = "";
    foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
    {
            toString += key + "=" + dict[key];
    }
    return toString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ShekHar_Pro's approach to use the serializer.  Only recommendation is to use json.net to serialize rather than the builtin JavaScriptSerializer since it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

I really like solutions with extension method above, but they are missing one little thing for future purpose - input parametres for separators, so:

```
    public static string ToPairString<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, string pairSeparator, string keyValueSeparator = "=")
    {
        return string.Join(pairSeparator, dictionary.Select(pair => pair.Key + keyValueSeparator + pair.Value));
    }
```

Example of using:

```
string result = myDictionary.ToPairString(Environment.NewLine, " with value: ");
```

Answer (score -5):

What you have to do, is to create a class extending `Dictionary` and overwrite the `ToString()` method.

See you

Comment: May I know Why someone pointed -1 to this? :) thanks, If I'm wrong I would like where I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but it doesn't provide sample code. Also, subclassing seems like an unnecessary hammer when you can just write an extension method as shown in some of the other answers; this also allows you to call the extension method directly on dictionaries you're getting from code outside your control where you wouldn't be able to just use your subclass.