# If has Method/extension method, then Call it

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am making a `ToDebugString()` method for dictionaries but I also want it to use the `ToDebugString()` method for any items if it is available for that type.

Since `ToDebugString()` is sometimes implemented as a extension method for native .NET types (like dictionary and list), I am having trouble checking for the method existence. I am only putting extension methods in a single class called `ExtensionMethods` so I may only have to search in one additional class.

The point of interest is here:

The `ToDebugString()` complains about type arguments. Also since `Value` is a generic type, it doesn't auto-suggest the `ToDebugString()` method so I assume there are problems there as well.

```
kv.Value.HasMethod("ToDebugString") ? kv.Value.ToDebugString() : kv.Value.ToString()
```

If I wasn't using native .NET types, implementing a common interface I think would be the solution.

---

Here is the full snippet:

```
// via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114514/796832
public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName) {
    var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
    return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
} 

// Convert Dictionary to string
// via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5899291/796832
public static string ToDebugString<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(", ", dictionary.Select(kv => kv.Key.ToString() + "=" + (kv.Value.HasMethod("ToDebugString") ? kv.Value.ToDebugString() : kv.Value.ToString())).ToArray()) + "}";
}
```

Also [here are a small tests](http://pastebin.com/nzzQfxuh) I made for trying to get `HasMethod()` to give the correct.

Comment: `typeof(ExtensionMethods).HasMethod()` is currently looking for the method on type `Type`, as you are passing it in as an object and calling `GetType()` on it, which will return `typeof(Type)`.

Comment: @DanBryant I was trying to follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15927145/796832) which does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but `typeof(ExtensionMethods).GetType() == typeof(Type)`, so if you say `typeof(ExtensionMethods).GetType().GetMethod()`, you are looking for a method on type Type.  You need to change your helper `HasMethod` to allow checking the type directly rather than the type of the instance.

Comment: @MLM, take a look this this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299515/reflection-to-identify-extension-methods   . Extensions methods does not belong to the type they extend. They belong to class where they are defined.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Thanks for reminding me of that question. I now have a method `HasMethodOrExtensionMethod` that works but this solves half of the problem. If the method doesn't exist it won't compile because I am trying to call a method that doesn't exist. See the *Update* section of the question.

Comment: @MLM, I've added the answer

Comment: You're attempting to use dynamic typing against static types.  It doesn't work.  C# does support dynamic types and it's possible you could apply it here.  However, why?  The compiler is telling you the extension method doesn't exist and wont exist until you create it.  Why do you want to call a function that you know doesn't exist?

Comment: @AaronCarlson I have already implemented what aleksey suggested and it works. His answer is messy but I plan to improve the question and answer with the final solution.

Comment: Please post your answer as answer and leave the question as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding extension methods is that they belong to the class they are declared in, not the class they are extending. So if you search for the extension method on the class it is extending where you expect it to be, it will not be there.

Thanks to [aleksey.berezan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248406/aleksey-berezan)'s comment for reminding me again of [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299526/796832) which has a great way to grab extension methods.

### Solution:

Here is the complete cleaned up solution. This code is also [available here](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius/blob/master/Radius/Assets/Scripts/Utility/ExtensionMethods.cs) in my project, [Radius: a Unity 3D project, on GitHub](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius).

It works by checking for `ToDebugString()` in the object class itself. Then searches for `ToDebugString()` extension methods in the `ExtensionMethods` class. If that fails as well, it just uses the normal `ToString()`.

```
// Convert Dictionary to string
// via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899291/796832
public static string ToDebugString<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(", ", dictionary.Select(kv => GetToDebugString(kv.Key) + "=" + GetToDebugString(kv.Value)).ToArray()) + "}";
}

static string GetToDebugString<T>(T objectToGetStringFrom)
{
    // This will try to call the `ToDebugString()` method from the class first
    // Then try to call `ToDebugString()` if it has an extension method in ExtensionMethods class
    // Otherwise just use the plain old `ToString()`

    // Get the MethodInfo
    // This will check in the class itself for the method
    var mi = objectToGetStringFrom.GetMethodOrNull("ToDebugString"); 

    string keyString = "";

    if(mi != null)
        // Get string from method in class
        keyString = (string)mi.Invoke(objectToGetStringFrom, null);
    else
    {
        // Try and find an extension method
        mi = objectToGetStringFrom.GetExtensionMethodOrNull("ToDebugString");

        if(mi != null)
            // Get the string from the extension method
            keyString = (string)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] {objectToGetStringFrom});
        else
            // Otherwise just get the normal ToString
            keyString = objectToGetStringFrom.ToString();
    }

    return keyString;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/299526/796832
static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetExtensionMethods(Assembly assembly, Type extendedType)
{
    var query = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
        where type.IsSealed && !type.IsGenericType && !type.IsNested
            from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            where method.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false)
            where method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == extendedType
            select method;
    return query;
}

public static MethodInfo GetMethodOrNull(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    // Get MethodInfo if it is available in the class
    // Usage:
    //      string myString = "testing";
    //      var mi = myString.GetMethodOrNull("ToDebugString"); 
    //      string keyString = mi != null ? (string)mi.Invoke(myString, null) : myString.ToString();

    var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    if(method != null)
        return method;

    return null;
}

public static MethodInfo GetExtensionMethodOrNull(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    // Get MethodInfo if it available as an extension method in the ExtensionMethods class
    // Usage:
    //      string myString = "testing";
    //      var mi = myString.GetMethodOrNull("ToDebugString"); 
    //      string keyString = mi != null ? (string)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] {myString}); : myString.ToString();

    Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(ExtensionMethods).Assembly;
    foreach (MethodInfo methodEntry in GetExtensionMethods(thisAssembly, objectToCheck.GetType()))
        if(methodName == methodEntry.Name)
            return methodEntry;

    return null;
}
```

If you have your extension methods somewhere else, be sure to edit this line in `GetExtensionMethodOrNull()`:

```
Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(ExtensionMethods).Assembly;
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your extension method does not get called is because extension methods belong to types where they are defined so such calls:

```
"Hello world".MyExtensionMethod()
```

under the hood gets converted to:

```
ExtensionMethods.MyExtensionMethod("Hello world"));// "Hello world".MyExtensionMethod()
```

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299515/reflection-to-identify-extension-methods/299526#299526) has some code example how to get all the extension methods for specific class, I've extended the code a bit and here's the code for running extension method by name:

```
    // the utility code

    internal static class ExtensionMethodsHelper
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, MethodInfo>> methodsMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, MethodInfo>>();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public static MethodInfo GetExtensionMethodOrNull(Type type, string methodName)
        {
            var methodsForType = methodsMap.GetOrAdd(type, GetExtensionMethodsForType);
            return methodsForType.ContainsKey(methodName)
                ? methodsForType[methodName]
                : null;
        }

        private static IDictionary<string, MethodInfo> GetExtensionMethodsForType(Type extendedType)
        {
            // WARNING! Two methods with the same name won't work here
            // for sake of example I ignore this fact
            // but you'll have to do something with that

            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .Select(asm => GetExtensionMethods(asm, extendedType))
                            .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Union(b))
                            .ToDictionary(mi => mi.Name, mi => mi);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetExtensionMethods(Assembly assembly, Type extendedType)
        {
            var query = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                        where type.IsSealed && !type.IsGenericType && !type.IsNested
                        from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static
                            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        where method.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false)
                        where method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == extendedType
                        select method;
            return query;
        }
    }

    // example: class with extension methods


    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string MyExtensionMethod(this string myString)
        {
            return "ranextension on string '" + myString + "'";
        }
    }

    // example: usage

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var mi = ExtensionMethodsHelper.GetExtensionMethodOrNull(typeof(string), "MyExtensionMethod");
            if (mi != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { "hello world" }));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("did't find extension method with name " + "MyExtensionMethod");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Update**
Let's take this piece of code:
`myTest.HasMethodOrExtensionMethod("MyExtensionMethod") ? myTest.MyExtensionMethod() :` "didnotrun"

It does not compile. How to get it working.

```
  // utility code
  public static class ExtensionMethods
  {
      public static string MyExtensionMethod(this string myString)
      {
          return "ranextension on string '" + myString + "'";
      }

      public static object InvokeExtensionMethod(this object instance, string methodName, params object[] arguments)
      {
          if (instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");

          MethodInfo mi = ExtensionMethodsHelper.GetExtensionMethodOrNull(instance.GetType(), methodName);
          if (mi == null)
          {
              string message = string.Format("Unable to find '{0}' extension method in '{1}' class.", methodName, instance);
              throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
          }

          return mi.Invoke(null, new[] { instance }.Concat(arguments).ToArray());
      }
  }

  // example usage    
  Console.WriteLine("hey".InvokeExtensionMethod("MyExtensionMethod"));
```

Comment: Clean up your answer and make a bit more precise so I can accept it. I have updated the question with the final solution I used.

Answer (score -1):

Your call to GetMethod is failing because the method you are looking for is static, and you are not including that flag in the GetMethod call.  Try this:

```
  public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
  {
     BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

     var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
     return type.GetMethod(methodName, flags) != null;
  }
```

Comment: I am still getting "didnotrun" on all of the tests using the updated function with flags.