# Dictionary<K,V>.ToString() more generic implementation

Tags: c#, dictionary, tostring

I have this question from [Most efficient Dictionary.ToString() with formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639094/most-efficient-dictionaryk-v-tostring-with-formatting), but my problem is if V is List, how to make it works. Now my solution is, 
  change

```
itemString.AppendFormat(format, item.Key, item.Value);
```

to

```
itemString.AppendFormat(format, item.Key, item.Value.ToDelimitedStr());
```

here is code of ToDelimitedStr:

```
    public static string ToDelimitedStr<T>(this T source)
    {
        // List<string> 
        if (source is IList &&
            source.GetType().IsGenericType)
        {
            Type t1 = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (t1.Name == "String")
                ((IEnumerable<string>)source).ToDelimitedString();
        }
        return source.ToString();
    }
```

which only work for `List<string>`. How I can make it more generic? 
Also, I'm thinking, maybe I should not work on the top of

```
public string DictToString<T, V>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, V>> items, string format)
```

I should create a new version like

```
public string DictListToString<T, List<V>>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, List<V>>> items, string format)
```

how about that?

Thank you so much

Wes

Comment: Are you asking how you can improve your `ToDelimitedStr` method, or how you can handle `Dictionary<K, V>` when V can be anything, but when it happens to be an `IEnumerable<T>` that it prints out every value?

Comment: Don't write a generic method that just checks if the type is a `List` internally.  If you want to do that, just have the parameter be a `List<T>` instead.  If you need to support a `Dictionary`, create a separate overload for it.

Comment: Hi adrianbanks, the later is my target. Improving ToDelimitedStr just the solution. At very beginning, I'm trying to find a way to override IEnumerable<T>.ToString(), because the default version output like 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but I like to prints out every value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string.Join`

```
return string.Join("," , (IList<T>)source);
```

I think it would be easier if you add an overloead for `ToDelimitedStr` which takes a `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter, then you don't need that type checks:

```
public static string ToDelimitedStr<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
     return string.Join(",", source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IEnumerable` and just call `ToString` on the items:

```
public static string ToDelimitedStr<T>(this T source)
{
    // Will work for ANY IEnumerable
    if (source is IEnumerable)     // <----------------
    {
        IEnumerable<string> items =
           ((IEnumerable)source).OfType<object>()
                                .Select(o => o.ToString());
        // convert items to a single string here...
        return string.Join(", ", items);
    }
    return source.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Selman22 There's not an overload that takes an `IEnumerable` - only `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.  In this case the underlying type of the collection is not known.  It could be extracted via reflection but that's uneccessary in this case.