# How to Output a C# Dictionary as C# code?

Tags: c#, dictionary, code-generation

How can I convert a Dictionary into the C# code that would define that dictionary? (Similar to `repr()` in python.)

Example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 4, "a" },
    { 5, "b" }
};

Console.WriteLine(dict.ToCsharpString());
```

Output:

```
Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 4, "a" },
    { 5, "b" }
}
```

I'm most interested in Dictionaries containing primitive types.

*Similar questions*: [Most efficient Dictionary.ToString() with formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639094/most-efficient-dictionaryk-v-tostring-with-formatting) (focused on efficiency), [Is there anyway to handy convert a dictionary to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899171/is-there-anyway-to-handy-convert-a-dictionary-to-string)
 (wants a different output format).

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON serializer/ deserializer as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797924/1974344)? JSON is really easy to process in .NET/C#.

Comment: Might the `Dictionary` have some form of custom comparer (e.g. case insensitive)?

Comment: @Odrai: I don't think a JSON serializer will output to C#? I use this for two purposes: quick debug logs (where C# is a familiar form for the data) and generating data that I later insert into my code.

Comment: `How can I convert a Dictionary into the C# code that would define that dictionary?` If you are trying to generate the code that created a dictionary, and the original code **used a custom comparer** are you expecting the generated code to also include the custom comparer?

Comment: @mjwills: No. I'm just looking for the keys & values to be the same. Not the configuration of the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639137/79125) on a related question, here's an extension method solution:

```
public static string ToCsharpString<TKey,TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> items) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    string type_name = items.GetType().Name;
    int index = type_name.LastIndexOf('`');
    if (index == -1) {
        index = type_name.Length;
    }
    str.Append(type_name, 0, index);
    str.AppendFormat("<{0}, {1}>", typeof(TKey).Name, typeof(TValue).Name);
    str.Append(" {\n");

    foreach (var item in items) {
        str.AppendFormat("\t{{ {0}, {1} }},\n", ToLiteral(item.Key), ToLiteral(item.Value));
    }
    str.Append("}");

    return str.ToString(); 
}

static string ToLiteral(object obj) {
    string input = obj as string;
    if (input == null)
        return obj.ToString();

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/79125
    using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")) {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is slightly different because it prints Framework Class Library type instead of primitive types (`Int32` instead of `int`), but it works pretty well:

```
Dictionary<Int32, String> {
    { 4, "a" },
    { 5, "b" },
}
```

[Try it out.](https://repl.it/@idbrii/Output-a-C-Dictionary-as-C-code)

Room for improvement:

- Handle recursion on embedded Dictionaries (but I don't think it's worth it due to the complexity of preventing infinite recursion).
- Maybe printing something nicer for nonprimitive types?